# query to count waiting in an OmniChannel queue DON'T WORKS

Tags: omnichannel, service

in the queue have five users waiting, but the query doesn't work, WHY?

[image]

Comment: I think you need to query [PendingServiceRouting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.omni_channel_dev.meta/omni_channel_dev/sforce_api_objects_pendingservicerouting.htm)

Comment: yes, you solved my problem, tks